# Explaining about SQL Server query Execution Plans and understanding Clustered and Nonclustered Indexes

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

I'm Christine and I'm a newbie. I would like to know if someone could help me clarify what I'm drilling down this execution plan as below :

[image]

Here's query generated from SQL server that is accompanied with this execution plan (with 3 tables) and index as follows :

[image]

1. How many types of indexes in execution plan are there? Currently I can see this execution plan with 3 types of indexes aforementioned that consist of : Index Scan, Clustered Index Scan and Clustered Index Seek
2. Which table has the best performance?
3. Which table needs applying index?
4. Which table needs requerying to increase performance for database?

Thanks in advance for your assistance in this matter.

Rgds,

Christine

Comment: Hi and welcome to DBA stack exchange. It would help if instead of an image including all information, you would post your query as an actual code block (allows us to copy it over if need be). Secondly your execution plan looks like an estimated plan, and not an 'actual plan'. Where you'd be looking for discrepancies to try and pinpoint bottlenecks.

Comment: Atm your advice/pointers would be more generic. I.e. using the variable in a where condition probably leaves the optimizer unable to determine the amount of records it gets back. And when it comes to Index useage. Seeks are better than Scans, and it's showing to at least use the One Nonclustered index, which is.. probably beneficial. Atm i'd probably think the 'worst' index useage is ProductInventory, because it's using a Clustered Index Scan. Which often is just the default action if you only have a primary key.

Comment: To allow us to see the internal operations, one can post the execution plan XML into [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) where we can then also look through it (works for both estimated plans and actual plans)

Comment: Dear @DKramer, thanks for your quick support. About detail of execution plan, you can check it out hereby : https://hackernoon.com/execution-plan-in-sql-server-4a8857e4542d. I would like to know that : does Clustured Index Scan apply for Index? And in 3 types of the indexes (Index Scan, Clustered Index Scan and Clustered Index Seek) what will be applied index?

Comment: To the command "Create Index" as link above, when creating an index by a column, moreover if the addition the other columns what will they have function?